# is there a compilation of Barisas?

Tags: product-recommendation

Knowing the codified Mishna is nice but since a lot of halacha is influenced by a Rabbi pulling a Barisa out of nowhere and changing the flow of the Gemara, they are obviously very important.

Is there a collection of all these Barisas?

Comment: In the vilna shas the Tosefta (the "main" collection of barisas, there are others) is printed at the back. You can also look for Chazon Yechescal, which is Dayan Abramsky's commentary on the Tosefta which prints the tosefta as well.  As

Comment: If they were collected they wouldn't be braisas anymore